# negative lookbehind regex assertion in python

Tags: python, regex

I am working on an application that has a search feature, in which I want to match the search patterns. The patterns can have the following forms:

- `search:'pattern'` and `search:"pattern"` (quoted search)
- `search:r'pattern'` and `search:r"pattern"` (regex search)
- `search:pattern` (unquoted search)

My regular expressions are:

```
quoted = re.compile(r'search:(?:\'|")([^"\']+)')
regex = re.compile(r'search:r(?:\'|")([^"\']+)')
unquoted = re.compile(r'search:(?<!r[\'"])([^ \'"]+)')
```

and my test string is

```
test_str = "search:foo search:'bar' search:\"baz\" search:r'blah' search:r\"bleh\""
```

The quoted and regex patterns are correctly matched, but the unquoted pattern (which should only match `foo`) doesn't match correctly, it behaves like if the negative lookbehind wasn't there. I also tried to remove the quotes (`[\'"]`) from the assertion, but it returns exactly the same result:

```
>>> unquoted.findall(test_str)
['foo', 'r', 'r']
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lookbehind assertion in `'search:(?<!r[\'"])([^ \'"]+)'` looks behind from the position just after the `h:` sequence so it never finds that `h:` is `r'` or `r"`
Replace with `(?!r[\'"])`

But I see another problem:

```
import re

quoted = re.compile(r'search:(?:[\'"])([^"\']+)')
regex = re.compile(r'search:r(?:[\'"])([^"\']+)')
unquoted = re.compile(r'search:(?!r[\'"])([^ \'"]+)')

test_str = "search:foo search:romeo "\
           "search:'bar' search:\"baz\" "\
           "search:r'blah' search:r\"bleh\""\
           "search:isn'it something to catch ?"

"""
•search:'pattern' and search:"pattern" (quoted search)
•search:r'pattern' and search:r"pattern" (regex search)
•search:pattern (unquoted search)

"""
print quoted.findall(test_str)
print
print regex.findall(test_str)
print
print unquoted.findall(test_str)
```

result

```
['bar', 'baz']

['blah', 'bleh']

['foo', 'romeo', 'isn']
```

Wouldn't you like to catch `isn'it` ?

Comment: oh, I misunderstood how negative lookbehind worked then, thank you so much!

Comment: Also, if you can use the spaces to split the string, you can get away without the assertions with this regex `search:([^r'"]|r[^'"]).*[^'"]`, http://goo.gl/ciCqAh

Comment: I can't, as a space could exist in the quoted search pattern

Comment: What do you think of ``unquoted = re.compile('search:(?!r?([\'"])[^ ]+(?<!\\1))([^ ]+)')`` ? It catches ``isn'it`` , not only ``isn`` (I made a mistake writing this: **isn'it** , it is not english, don't stop at this) - My name is Jeff Etoubien :))